# HTML/CSS - Keep elements in the same line even with <br> tag

Tags: html, css

Is there possible to keep elements inside a DIV, in the same line, even if i put a BR tag after elements ? For example:

DIV
 ↑ → Full Name (a br here)
IMAGE → Address (another br here)
 ↓ → Tel
/DIV

And display exactly this example ?

↑
I
M → Full Name
A → Addres
G → Tel
E
 ↓

Keeping next to each other. I'm using this code, but it doesn't working like i want;

```html
      <div style="white-space:nowrap; display:inline-block;">
       <a href="http://www.whateveraddress.com"><img src="localhost/xrEN.png" width="165" height="50"></a>
       <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Full Name</b><br>
       <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Address</b><br>
       <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Tel</b><br>
      </div>
```

Comment: looks like a typical use of float to start with : `a{float:left;}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: left`.

```
a {
  float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeh6unqf/5/)

If you have the control of the html source, then use Flexbox.

```
<div class='main'>
  <div>
    <a href="https://www.whateveraddress.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" width="165" height="50"></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Full Name</b><br>
    <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Address</b><br>
    <b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Tel</b><br>
  </div>

</div>
```

And then add style.

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aeh6unqf/9/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with img align attribute, like this (for html4):

```html
<div>
<a href="http://www.whateveraddress.com"><img src="localhost/xrEN.png" width="165" height="50" align="left"></a>
<b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Full Name</b><br>
<b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Address</b><br>
<b style="color:black; font-size:12; font-family:Arial;">Tel</b><br>
</div>
```

For html5 you can use css float attribute

Comment: The `align` attribute is obsolete

Comment: obsolete attribute for almost 15 years ... float:left is used nowdays ....

Comment: @j08691 it is deprecated only in html5, anyway - updated answer

Comment: @G-Cyr actually, only 4 years :)

Comment: @IlyaBursov okay , i thought that was since html 4.01 from where i started to mind IE6 bugs and fully enjoyed FF 1.0  ;) but maybe i was too much minding standards at this time. (from all IE7 was the worth, IE5 was fun but too much security troubles about it (msdos 3->6.2 was my first play grounds) But 4 years, i do not believe it, i stopped professionnal activities 8 years ago, and those attributes where already obsolete back then ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr officially html 5 was released 2014, draft existed long before of course

Comment: Works! Thank you guys !